# remove the numeric ticks and keep column names

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to find the relationship between the null values of a column and other columns.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 10))
for index, column in zip(range(4), ['Region', 'Sex', 'Age', 'Citizenship']):
   value_count = cps[column][cps.Married.isnull()].value_counts()
   ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, index+1)
   value_count.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

My problem is the damn xticks showing unnecessary numbers instead of just the names of the columns.

How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `plt.xticks(range(4), ['Region', 'Sex', 'Age', 'Citizenship'])` before the tight_layout.